# \IfStrEqCase having problem with last optional parameter

Tags: xstring

It's been a while since I asked an embarrassing question, and am pretty sure this is another one of those:  This code below attempts to use `\IfStrEqCase` from [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) and results in:

```
Runaway argument? 
{document} \par \par \par \documentclass {article} \usepackage {pgfpl\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xs@testcase.
```

for the case where none of the cases match, but I don't know why.

### Notes:

- This is especially embarrassing as I answered [What's the best/right way to test an argument to a macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/whats-the-best-right-way-to-test-an-argument-to-a-macro/33581#33581) using `\IfStrEqCase` and that code works just fine.  Hence, don't think it is a version issue.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

%\newcommand{\CaseVar}{case A}% This works
%\newcommand{\CaseVar}{case B}%  This works
\newcommand{\CaseVar}{case C}% This does NOT!!!

\begin{document}
    \IfStrEqCase{\CaseVar}{%
        {case A}{Found Case A}
        {case B}{Found Case B}
    }[Oppsss, unknown case '\CaseVar'.]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, it seems as I need to actually go through the effort of posting a question before figuring out a solution. It seems that adding a `%` after the `Case b` closing `}` solves it, but why?????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The internal macro that checks the cases is `\@xs@testcase`. Using `\tracingmacros=1` with your original input, we find:

```
\@xs@testcase #1#2#3\@xs@nil ->\@xs@reserved@E {\CaseVar }{#1}{#2}{\@xs@ifempty
 {#3}{Oppsss, unknown case '\CaseVar '.}{\@xs@testcase #3\@xs@nil }}
#1<-case A
#2<-Found Case A
#3<- {case B}{Found Case B}
```

for the first test; you can see the blank space resulting from the end-of-line after `{Found Case A}`. This is not a problem, because this space will not be considered at the next test:

```
\@xs@testcase #1#2#3\@xs@nil ->\@xs@reserved@E {\CaseVar }{#1}{#2}{\@xs@ifempty
 {#3}{Oppsss, unknown case '\CaseVar '.}{\@xs@testcase #3\@xs@nil }}
#1<-case B
#2<-Found Case B
#3<-
```

Do you see the problem? The third argument to `\@xs@testcase` is delimited by `\@xs@nil` and in this case a blank space is as good as an argument as any list of tokens. TeX disregards spaces only when looking for *undelimited* arguments.

Add `%` at the end of lines, if you use that kind of input style.

Probably `xstring` should use a test for `\ifblank` rather than `\ifempty`.

Answer (score 0):

Here a workaround: redefine `\IfStrEqCase` so that it always includes a matching case. The same approach also works for \IfEqCase.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

%\newcommand{\CaseVar}{case A}% This works
%\newcommand{\CaseVar}{case B}%  This works
\newcommand{\CaseVar}{case C}% Prints "Unknown case 'case C'."

% redefine \IfStrEqCase
\let\XstringIfStrEqCase\IfStrEqCase
\renewcommand\IfStrEqCase[2]{%
    \XstringIfStrEqCase{#1}{%
        #2%
        {#1}{Unknown case '#1'.}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \IfStrEqCase{\CaseVar}{%
        {case A}{Found Case A}
        {case B}{Found Case B}
    }
\end{document}
```